# Install SwiftKeychainWrapper manually

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, xcode8

I would like to install [SwiftKeychainWrapper](https://github.com/jrendel/SwiftKeychainWrapper) manually because I get error when I try to install it using CocoaPods.

In description it says that I need to download and drop `KeychainWrapper.swift` and `KeychainItemAcessibility.swift` into my project.

I clicked on Clone or download -> Download ZIP. In downloaded SwiftKeychainWrapper folder there are `KeychainWrapper.swift` and `KeychainItemAcessibility.swift` files. I drag and dropped them to my project under the same root where there are Main.storyboard, AppDelegate.swift,...

Then is says to use the keychain wrapper in your app, import SwiftKeychainWrapper into the file(s) where you want to use it.

I added `import SwiftKeychainWrapper` to a file where I want to use it and I get error `No such module 'SwiftKeychainWrapper'`.

What am I doing wrong, why can't I use it?

Comment: If you added the files to your project manually you shouldn't have to import anything to use them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as *@dan* said you don't need to import any other modules if you add source files directly to your project. When a library is added via `cocoapods`, all of it's sources are in a separate module and you need to do `import ModuleName` to make them accessible.

If your read carefully github instructions, you'll find that for manual approach you should only copy the files and nothing more:

> Manually
>
> Download and drop KeychainWrapper.swift and
>   KeychainItemAcessibility.swift into your project.

P.S. Also make sure that you copy those files into you project folder before dragging them into `Xcode` because that will just add links to files in your `Downloads` folder or wherever they are placed.